# Rank of a matrix. Is it correct?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

Given the matrix $B∈ M_3(Z_7)$

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 3 & 1 \\
    4 & 0 & 2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Is the rank of this matrix $2$? I calculated the determinant of the matrix

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 \\
    1 & 3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

and it is equal to $5$ so since the determinant of this $2 x 2$ sub-matrix is non-zero it means that the rank is $2$, right?

Comment: You are right, of course, if $\Delta=0$.

Comment: It means the rank is _at least_ $2$, since the first two columns are linearly independent. You haven't disproved rank $3$.

Comment: The first row plus $2$-times the second row is the third one. So the rank *is* equal to $2$.

Comment: @Arthur So if the exercise asks me to calculate the rank it could also not be $2$?

Comment: @Jonsa You have proven that the rank cannot be $0$ or $1$. You need to either calculate the determinant of the entire $3\times 3$ matrix or, as Dietrich said, find a linear dependence, before you can tell whether it's $2$ or $3$.

Comment: You already had questions about the rank in $M_3(\mathbb{F}_9)$.

Comment: @Jonsa Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 1):

Note that the rank of $B$ can be viewed as $n$ where $n$ is the **size of the largest non-zero** $n\times n$ sbmatrix with non-zero determinant

In this case $\det B=12$ then $\text{rank} (B)=3$.

[Rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra))

Answer (score 0):

You are right if $\Delta=0$ and indeed,  $\Delta=0.$

Comment: If the determinant of the original matrix was non-zero what was the rank?

Comment: If so, then it's $3$.